# Remix Warning : Assert

Tags: solidity, remix, require, assert

I am trying to compile a contract on remix and have run into the following warning :

> Use *assert(x)* if you never ever want *x* to be false, not
>   in any circumstance (apart from a bug in your code). Use
>   *require(x)* if *x* can be false, due to e.g. invalid input
>   or a failing external component.

The parts of my code that use assert are :

```
assert(checkPlayerExists(msg.sender) == false);
assert(number >= 1 && number <= 10);
assert(msg.value >= minimumBet);
```

Would love someone to explain this as it seems a bit cryptic.

Comment: assert(checkPlayerExists(msg.sender)) will return false and abort execution. Try to cut ‘== false’ and run code again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. In my case, I want the call to be terminated if the player already exists . Would taking it out not do the opposite? would it be safer using `require`?

Comment: Rob Hitchens already answered this question before me. As it is stated in [docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html), assert is meant to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a misuse of `assert` because, depending on input, the expressions may evaluate to `false`. Use `require()` instead.

`assert()` is meant to check for logical errors in the contract itself. Asserts state facts that must always be true under any circumstances, so any possibility of false would be a logic issue.

Consider:

```
uint balanceAlice = 10;
uint balanceBob = 5;
uint conserveFunds = balanceAlice + balanceBob;

// do stuff
uint conservedFunds = balanceAlice + balanceBob;

// whatever we did, we should always end up with the same funds accounted for.
// ANY departure from this principal means the contract contains a logic error. 
assert(conserveFunds == conservedFunds)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have replace the `asserts` with `require` but the warning is still there...is this expected behaviour?

Comment: Maybe post the whole works so we can replicate it. I wouldn't expect `require` to behave the same way. Maybe it's a different complaint.